# How to install Carton module into local project with perlbrew?

Tags: perl, perl-module, perlbrew, cpanm

I use `perlbrew` to easy switch between perl.
I use `Carton` to install modules only for current project into `/local` directory.

But when I deploy application on new host.

I do:

```
perlbrew install -v -j 8 --notest --switch perl-5.30.3
perlbrew install-cpanm
cpanm Carton
```

But last step will install `Carton` into perlbrew `libs`

Is there a way to install `Carton` into my project `local/lib/perl5` directory?

*I want to keep base perlbrew clean*

Comment: This is so backwards X_X I'm always recommending that people install a local `perl` to avoid "local libs" and all the problems this causes. You have that, but you seek to reintroduce all the problems! Nothing stops you from having more than one install of a version of Perl is you want a clean one and a not-so-clean one. See the `--as` argument of `perlbrew install`.

Answer (score 2):

To install modules into your own directory we can use `--local-lib` option.
It is mentioned [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus#Where-does-this-install-modules-to?-Do-I-need-root-access?) and described at examples `cpanm --help`

```
cpanm --local-lib ./local
```

probably useful options for this task are:

```
-n,--notest        Do not run unit tests
--self-contained   Install all non-core modules, even if they're already installed
```

If you do deploy often probably you do not need to retest each time. This is meaningless.

Second option is useful when you want modules to be installed into you local directory despite on they are already installed into system/brew perl